# Sequential cascade Observables according result from previous response and remap to new data object

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have difficulties using the power of `Observables` i.e. `RxJs 6` to correctly `pipe, tap, map, mergemap` or whatever my `HttpClient` requests. The version hell with all the different functions makes it not very easy...

So what I need is to first make a REST call, then depending on the result probably do a second REST call and map the potentially two received data objects in one new data object. The function should return an `Observable`.

So currently, I solved it with a `subject` that I am be able to do manually / sequentially what I need. The function returns a `Subject`, not an Observable in this case. But since the caller just subscribes to this function, it works.
To mention is that the two service functions below (`userService.loadUserDetails()` and `adminService.getAdminData()`) just returns observables they get from `HttpClient`.

So can anybody help me translate this example code below into typically **RxJs 6** code?

```
myFunction(): Observable<any> {
   const s = new Subject();
    let obj: any = {};

    this.userService.loadUserDetails().subscribe((userDetails) => {
        obj.user = userDetails;
        if (userDetails.authorities.includes('ADMIN')) {
            this.adminService.getAdminData().subscribe((adminData) => {
                obj.adminData = adminData;
                s.next(obj);
                s.complete();
            });
        } else {
            s.next(obj);
            s.complete();
        }
    });

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) to chain and return conditionally

Update: changed mergeMap to switchMap Incase inner observable is a continuous stream and when source observable emit it will also cancel the inner observable .

```
    this.userService.loadUserDetails().pipe(
    switchMap(user=>
      user.authorities.includes('ADMIN')) ?
      this.adminService.getAdminData().map(adminData=>({adminData,user})):
      Observable.of({user}))
      )
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Why is the last `subscribe() ` needed? Which is the observable to return? Thanks very much!

Comment: Good solution, just tested here https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-count-shgzzs

Comment: In contrast, mergeMap allows for multiple inner subscriptions to be active at a time.
Maybe `switchMap` best suited here?

Comment: I would like to accept your answer. So please add some more comments and probably change `mergeMap` to `switchMap` and describe why. Thank you very much!

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own observer. `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
   this.userService.loadUserDetails().subscribe((userDetails) => {
        obj.user = userDetails;
        if (userDetails.authorities.includes('ADMIN')) {
            this.adminService.getAdminData().subscribe((adminData) => {
                obj.adminData = adminData;
                observer.next(obj);
            });
        } else {
            observer.next(obj);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks you too for your answer. However, I will select the one above. Anyway +1